# OpenCV Explanation solvenpn

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-solvepnp

Can anyone give me more explanation about the opencv function `solvepnp()`? 
The opencv documentation says

```
bool cv::solvePnP   (
        InputArray      objectPoints,
        InputArray      imagePoints,
        InputArray      cameraMatrix,
        InputArray      distCoeffs,
        OutputArray     rvec,
        OutputArray     tvec,
        bool            useExtrinsicGuess = false,
        int             flags = SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE)
```

I'm wondering what the `objectPoints`, `imagePoints` and `cameraMatrix` are. I have once calibrated my camera and have a parameter xml file from it, can i use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used when you have for example a 3D model of an object and you have a view of it in the real world, it will give you an approximate position and orientation of the camera towards the object.
For example:

- objectPoints – Array of object points in the object coordinate space, 3xN/Nx3 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 3-channel, where N is the number of points. vector can be also passed here.
- imagePoints – Array of corresponding image points, 2xN/Nx2 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 2-channel, where N is the number of points. vector can be also passed here.

You can find the rest at this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#bool%20solvePnP(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20flags))